# Don't change resoucre image

Tags: android

I want to make a dynamic image by two static image, but this code just flash of one static image, now i want to flash two image respectively in 4s.

```
<ImageSwitcher
    android:id="@+id/imageswitcherID"
    <!-- insert another value to the view like layout width and height or margin -->
    android:inAnimation="@anim/fade_in"
    android:outAnimation="@anim/fade_out"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview1"
        <!-- another value here -->
        android:background="@drawable/your_drawable01"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview2"
        <!-- another value here -->
        android:background="@drawable/your_drawable02"
        />

</ImageSwitcher>
```

and now continue to your activity, create thread to loop for 4 seconds

```
int seconds = 0;
ImageSwitcher imgswitch;
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

    imgswitch = (ImageSwitcher)findViewById(R.id.imageswitcherID);

    SwitchingImages();
}
...
private void SwitchingImages(){
    Thread SwImg = new thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try{
                while(seconds <= 4){
                    sleep(1000); //sleep for 1 seconds
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                        @Override
                        public void run(){
                            imgswitch.showNext(); //will switch images every 1 seconds
                            if(seconds >= 5){
                                return; //stop the thread when 4 seconds elapsed
                            }
                            seconds += 1;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    SwImg.start();
}
```

Comment: Do you just want the image to switch just once after 4 seconds, or repeatedly, every 4 seconds?

Comment: i just want it to switch just once 4 seconds. but code just show one image. i want show 2 images respectively once after 4s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite easy to do with a `Runnable` and the `View.postDelayed()` method. Remove the `SwitchingImages()` method, and put this after the `imgswitch = ...` line.

```
imgswitch.postDelayed(
    // Here we create an anonymous Runnable
    // to switch the image and repost
    // itself every 0.5 * 1000 milliseconds
    // until count = 8
    new Runnable()
    {
        int count = 0;

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            if (count < 4 * 2)
            {
                imgswitch.showNext();
                count++;
                imgswitch.postDelayed(this, 500);
            }
        }
    }
    , 500);
```

If you want it to end on the other image, add or subtract `1` from `4 * 2`.

Comment: Of course, this will only work if you're sure the `ImageSwitcher`'s images and animations are correct.

Comment: Thanks, but it don't work that i want, you have changed 2 images appear in 4s, but i want every 0,5s image a will replace image b, and oppositely. and after 4s it will end.

Comment: Ok, let me see if I understand. You want the images to switch every 0.5 seconds, and then stop switching after 4 seconds. Is this right?